# How to attain atomicity while publishing kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

I have a scenario where I will be iterating through a set of records that will be fetched from database and after fetching I will be iterating through those records and will be pushing each record to kafka topic. Now let us assume I have retrieved 10 records and in the iteration I have pushed first 5 records and there is some exception on the 6th record I want to revert back the messages that are pushed into the topic. This is similar to database transactionality. Can we attain atomicity in kafka?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, atomicity can be achieved, but not when you introduce multiple, unrelated systems. Suggestion would be to use Debezium / CDC rather than query the database in your own app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use transactions; the record(s) will remain in the log and kafka puts a marker in the log to indicate whether the transaction was committed or rolled back.

Consumers must use `isolation.level=read_committed` to avoid getting rolled back records.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#transactions

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level

Comment: can the consumers use different isolation levels for different topics?

Comment: You would need multiple consumers; the setting is one per consumer, regardless of how many topics it is consuming from.

Comment: I have to send data in huge numbers(around 1 million)…How does transaction timeout pand out in this scenario? Is there a better way to send huge number of records from database to kafka attaining atomicity

Comment: I see you asked a new question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71655712/better-approach-to-send-bulk-data-from-database-to-kafka-using-spring-kafka ; it has nothing to do with Spring, which just delegates to the `kafka-clients`. You might need to increase the https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_transaction.timeout.ms

Answer (score 0):

> revert back the messages that are pushed into the topic

Once data is in the topic it cannot be modified; you'd need to delete the entire topic and restart from the very beginning