# Better approach to send bulk data from database to kafka using spring-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, transactions, spring-kafka, producer

I have a scenario where I need to send bulk data(more than a million records) to kafka topic. Fetch data from database and iterate through each record while publishing each into kafka topic. Currently I have added kafka transactionality and achieved atomicity(publishing everything or nothing). But I am getting gateway timeout exception when I tried publishing more than 35k records within a same transaction.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario in spring kafka?

Comment: Why not use Debezium snapshot features?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to tweak the configurations in order to be able to send more records in a single transaction, or improve performance, for example by tweaking the [batch.size](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_batch.size) or the [transaction.timeout](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_transaction.timeout.ms).

But in my experience, trying to do a one-by-one or all-at-once approach is usually not a good idea - the former tends to be inefficient, and the later will likely be susceptible to hitting some limit as data grows in size.

So, unless you really need the 1 million messages to be sent atomically, what I would try to do in your case is to deliver the records in batches - maybe 30K records is a good batch size, and just commit each batch. So you fetch 30K records from the database, send the records, commit, and repeat until all records are sent.

That would probably be more performant and also more scalable as there's no limit on how many records you can send this way.

Comment: If we do it in batch…lets assume there is some failure while publishing..how can we ensure which batch has been published and which is not?

Comment: If you don't need exactly once guarantees you can have a DB commit as part of the transaction. Of course, if the DB commit fails after the Kafka transaction is commited, the batch will be sent again. If you need exactly once guarantees, you can have a separate topic for controlling the batches, and include sending a record to that topic with the updated batch control as part of the original transaction. That way if one record publishing fails, both will be rolled back.